# How to add more than 50 ACL in one endpoint of Classic Azure Virtual machine

Tags: azure, networking

I have one classic machine in Azure having few endpoints, each endpoints have ACL (Access control list) .
However I am not able to add more than 50 ACL in one particular end point ( for example , HTTPs endpoint)

[Error from Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJdfW.png)

50 is the maximum limit to add ACL , is there any way to add more than 50 acl or allow more than 50 IP for a particular endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to add ACL above the maximum limit value 50 referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).
[image]

An ACL provides the ability to selectively permit or deny traffic for a virtual machine endpoint. It's used for the classic deployment model. It's recommended to use the Resource Manager deployment model. Then you could use the [security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview) to filter network traffic go inside or outside of the subnet level or NIC level.

In this case, you could consider migrating your VM from the Classic to Resource Manager deployment model following this [article](http://%20how%20to%20migrate%20infrastructure%20as%20a%20service%20(IaaS)%20resources%20from%20the%20Classic%20to%20Resource%20Manager%20deployment%20models).

Comment: It does not allow more than 50 ACL , but is there any way we can add new IP ( in NSG level  as classic server also support classic nsg ).We can't move to RM at this moment.any way thanks @Nancy Xiong

Comment: In ASM you had the possibility to link NSG to VM, NIC and subnet levels. Refer to [this1](https://robertsmit.wordpress.com/2017/09/11/step-by-step-azure-network-security-groups-nsg-security-center-azure-nsg-network/) and [this2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2016/05/14/azure-network-security-groups-nsg-best-practices-and-lessons-learned/)

Comment: In your classic NSG, you could add the new IP via security rule---advanced----CIDR block.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative solution:

1. Back up of all endpoint and ACL from the server
2. Removed all ACL ( IP ) , no need to remove endpoints ( i.e 80, 443 etc.)
3. Created classic NSG attached to server ( Classic NSG have some limitations for example, you can not add multiple IP using comma separated in one rule rather you can add the range)
4. You can add maximum 1000 rule in the NSG

Try this, it is tested.